# Display data from two tables - PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, get, notice, undefined-index

I've two tables in database 1. post and 2. OS

```
post:
+----+------------+-------+-------+-----+--------+------+-----+-------+
| id |    title   | metaD | metaK | img | author | date | cat |  text |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-----+--------+------+-----+-------+
| 1  | some title |  data | data  |data | data   | data | app |  data |
| 2  | title2     |  data | data  |data | data   | data | os  |  data |
| 3  | title3     |  data | data  |data | data   | data | oth |  data |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-----+--------+------+-----+-------+

os:
+------+----------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+
| osId |  ostitle |   osimg  | oscpuM | oscpuR | osramM | osramR | oshdM | oshdR | osgM | osgR | osdown |
+----+------------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+
| 1  | title8     |  name    | here comes text | data   | data   | data  | data  | data | data | data   |
| 2  | title2     |  name    | here comes text | data   | data   | data  | data  | data | data | data   |
| 3  | title4     |  name    | here comes text | data   | data   | data  | data  | data | data | data   |
+----+------------+----------+-----------------+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+------+--------+
```

and code:

```
//get data from "post" 
$post = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'";
    $post1 = mysql_query($post);
    $postV = mysql_fetch_array($post1);

    $postID = $postV['id'];
    $postTitle = $postV['title'];
    $postD = $postV['metaD'];
    $postK = $postV['metaK'];
    $postImg = $postV['img'];
    $postAuthor = $postV['author'];
    $postDate = $postV['date'];
    $postCat = $postV['cat'];
    $postText = $postV['text'];

//get data from "os"
    $os = "SELECT * FROM os WHERE ostitle='{$_GET['ostitle']}'";
    $os1 = mysql_query($os);
    $osV = mysql_fetch_array($os1);

    $osID = $osV['osId'];
    $osTitle = $osV['ostitle'];
    $osImg = $osV['osimg'];
    $osCpuM = $osV['oscpuM'];
    $osCpuR = $osV['oscpuR'];
    $osRamM = $osV['osramM'];
    $osRamR = $osV['osramR'];
    $osHdM = $osV['oshdM'];
    $osHdR = $osV['oshdR'];
    $osGM = $osV['osgM'];
    $osGR = $osV['osgR'];
    $osDown = $osV['osdown'];

    //dispaly post
    <?php
    echo "<img class='view_newsimg' src='$postImg'>
    <h3 class='lath'>$postTitle</h3>
    <ul class='det'>
    <li class='adc'>avtori: $postAuthor</li>
    <li class='adc'>TariRi: $postDate</li>
    <li class='adc'>kategoria: $postCat</li>
    </ul>
    <p class='news'>
    $postText";

//display from "os"
    $osif = $postV['cat'];

    if ($osif == 'os')
    {
    echo "<div class='os1'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>procesori</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>operatiuli mexsiereba</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>adgili myar diskze</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>grafikuli baraTi</div>
    </div>
    <div class='os1'>
    <div>minimaluri</div>
    <div>$osCpuM</div>
    <div>$osRamM</div>
    <div>$osHdM</div>
    <div>$osGM</div>
    </div>
    <div class='os1'>
    <div>rekomendebuli</div>
    <div>$osCpuR</div>
    <div>$osRamR</div>
    <div>$osHdR</div>
    <div>$osGR</div>
    </div>";
    }
    ?>
```

url for this page is : ".com/view.php?id=2ostitle=title2"
but ihave this error: " Notice: Undefined index: ostitle in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\LinuxOid.com\blocks\db3.php on line 54 " ( this is : $os = "SELECT * FROM os WHERE ostitle='{$_GET['ostitle']}'"; )

how i can solve this?

Comment: not `id=2ostitle=title2` it must be like `id=2&ostitle=title2`

Comment: thanks. it isnot showing this notice. but displayng nothing from table "os"

Comment: There's a `<?php` in `//dispaly post
    <?php
    echo "<img class='view_newsimg' src='$postImg'>` which shouldn't be there. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Never pass data directly from _get. And mysql_query is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss & in url change this line

```
.com/view.php?id=2ostitle=title2
```

To

```
.com/view.php?id=2&ostitle=title2
```

EDIT:use this code

```
<?php
    //get data from "post" 
    $post = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE id='{$_GET['id']}'";
    $post1 = mysql_query($post);
    $postV = mysql_fetch_array($post1);
    $postID = $postV['id'];
    $postTitle = $postV['title'];
    $postD = $postV['metaD'];
    $postK = $postV['metaK'];
    $postImg = $postV['img'];
    $postAuthor = $postV['author'];
    $postDate = $postV['date'];
    $postCat = $postV['cat'];
    $postText = $postV['text'];
//get data from "os"
    $os = "SELECT * FROM os WHERE ostitle='{$_GET['ostitle']}'";
    $os1 = mysql_query($os);
    $osV = mysql_fetch_array($os1);
    $osID = $osV['osId'];
    $osTitle = $osV['ostitle'];
    $osImg = $osV['osimg'];
    $osCpuM = $osV['oscpuM'];
    $osCpuR = $osV['oscpuR'];
    $osRamM = $osV['osramM'];
    $osRamR = $osV['osramR'];
    $osHdM = $osV['oshdM'];
    $osHdR = $osV['oshdR'];
    $osGM = $osV['osgM'];
    $osGR = $osV['osgR'];
    $osDown = $osV['osdown'];

    //dispaly post
    echo "<img class='view_newsimg' src='{$postImg}'>
    <h3 class='lath'>{$postTitle}</h3>
    <ul class='det'>
    <li class='adc'>avtori: {$postAuthor}</li>
    <li class='adc'>TariRi: {$postDate}</li>
    <li class='adc'>kategoria: {$postCat}</li>
    </ul>
    <p class='news'>{$postText}";
   //display from "os"
    $osif = $postV['cat'];
    if ($osif == 'os')
    {
    echo "<div class='os1'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>procesori</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>operatiuli mexsiereba</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>adgili myar diskze</div>
    <div class='os1_1'>grafikuli baraTi</div>
    </div>
    <div class='os1'>
    <div>minimaluri</div>
    <div>{$osCpuM}</div>
    <div>{$osRamM}</div>
    <div>{$osHdM}</div>
    <div>{$osGM}</div>
    </div>
    <div class='os1'>
    <div>rekomendebuli</div>
    <div>{$osCpuR}</div>
    <div>{$osRamR}</div>
    <div>{$osHdR}</div>
    <div>{$osGR}</div>
    </div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks. it isnot showing this notice. but displayng nothing from table "os"

Answer (score 0):

There's some problem in url. It should be like

com/view.php?id=2&ostitle=title2